# Problem 2.4, Chapter 3 from Artin

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A touch of background: I'm a CS prof headed back to get a math PhD, which means I have to pass the
qualifying exams next summer, so I'm studying now. One of my texts is *Algebra*, by
Michael Artin.
For some reason, I am unable to solve what I would consider a pretty remedial question in chapter 3.
This says to me that I am lacking some important understanding.

Here is the question:

Consider the following system of linear equations $AX = B$:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
6 & -3 \\\\
2 & 6
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\\\
x_2
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
3 \\\\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

1. Solve the system in $\mathbb{F}_p$ when $p = 5, 11, 17$.
2. Determine the number of solutions when $p = 7$.

Here is my solution:

First, as a sanity check, I'll compute the determinant, $\det A$.
I believe I can compute it in $\mathbb{Z}$ and then "take modulos"
to get the determinant modulo $p$ for the different values of $p$.

$$
\begin{align}
\det A &= 6 \cdot 6 - (-3) \cdot 2 \\\\
&= 42\\\\
&= 2 \pmod{5}\\\\
&= 0 \pmod{7}\\\\
&= 9 \pmod{11}\\\\
&= 8 \pmod{17}.
\end{align}
$$

So, the answer to part 2 is obvious -- there are zero solutions. For part 1, I attempted to solve it using row reduction. Here are my steps:

\begin{align}
&
\begin{bmatrix}
6 & -3 & 3\\\\
2 & 6 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\text{ Augmented matrix;}\\\\
&
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -21 & 0\\\\
2 & 6 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\text{ subtract } 3 \text{ times row } 2 \text{ from row } 1\text{;}\\\\
&
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0\\\\
2 & 6 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\text{ multiply row } 1 \text{ by } -\frac{1}{21} \text{;}\\\\
&
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0\\\\
2 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\text{ subtract } 6 \text{ times  row } 1 \text{ from row } 2 \text{;}\\\\
&
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0\\\\
1 & 0 & \frac{1}{2}
\end{bmatrix}
\text{ multiply  row } 2 \text{ by } \frac{1}{2}.
\end{align}

At this point, I'm ready to declare $x_1 = 0$ and $x_2 = \frac{1}{2}$. There's just
one problem. If I carry out the multiplication, I get the following equations:

\begin{align}
6 x_1 - 3 x_2 = 3 \\\\
2 x_1 + 6 x_2 = 1
\end{align}

And, as is obvious, the solution is actually the other way around:
$x_1 = \frac{1}{2}$ and $x_2 = 0$.

Where is my misunderstanding?

Comment: There are 7 solutions mod 7, $x_1 = 4-3x_2$

Comment: Determinant 0 does not automatically mean "no solutions", it means no *unique* solution. Modulo 7, the two equations are scalar multiples of one another (the second is $-2$ times the first), so you will have multiple solutions.

Comment: The title is inappropriate. The problem is nothing like "oddly difficult". Perhaps you can add another description, if you like ( I have edited it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not bring the matrix to reduced row echelon form because row 2 has a leading 1 before row 1. You need to exchange the two rows. Then you will get the desired solution.

$$
\vdots \\
\left[\begin{array}{lll}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & \frac{1}{2}
\end{array}\right] \text { multiply row } 2 \text { by } \frac{1}{2} \text {. }
\\
\left[\begin{array}{lll}
1 & 0 & \frac{1}{2}\\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}\right] \text {Swap rows 1 and 2.}
$$

So we see that $x_1=1/2$ and $x_2=0$.

Comment: Holy cow, that was easy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are two, maybe three issues. One is quite simple: from: $$\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\1&0&1/2\end{bmatrix}$$We see we need $0x_1+x_2=0$ and $x_1+0x_2=1/2$, so you find $x_1=1/2$ and $x_2=0$ there, as you should. I think you just mixed the two up; easily done.

The second issue is that the determinant equalling zero (or, more generally, a noninvertible element) does *not* mean no solutions exist. At least for matrices over a field, it means that *either* no solutions exist *or* solutions exist but the solutions are non-unique. All it actually means is that the matrix is not invertible, and the rank nullity theorem allows you to deduce the claims I made. So, you still need to check the case modulo $7$.

The third "issue" is that you should be grateful these were all prime numbers, hence their modular arithmetic is a field and you really can treat multiplication by $6$ as multiplication by a nonzero invertible scalar, etc. Maybe you were keeping track of that, maybe you weren't. I don't know but it is still worth mentioning.

Comment: Thanks. For the third issue can you expound a bit more? Is that to do with where I decided to perform all the arithmetic in Z (it's Q really, I guess)? I am thinking that if it were something like $\mathbb{F}_3$, for example, then 6 would be problematic?

Comment: @BlueGhost For example $6$ would be problematic in $\Bbb F_3$ as the elementary row reduction techniques are secretly multiplying by *invertible* elementary matrices… but the one corresponding to scalar multiplication is not invertible if you multiply by a non-invertible scalar. But $6$ would also be problematic in $\Bbb Z/10\Bbb Z$, even though $6$ is not zero. Only for prime modulus can you expect all nonzero elements to be invertible. If you use non-invertible matrix operations you can’t expect a one to one correlation between solutions to the reduced and original equations.